# Create dataframe out of dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary that looks as below:

```
Tablas = 
{'__v': 0,
 '_id': 'a',
 'approved': True}
{'__v': 1,
 '_id': 'b',
 'approved': True}
{'__v': 2,
 '_id': 'c',
 'approved': True}
```

I would like to loop through the 3 elements of the dictionary and add the elements to a data frame in a table containing three rows of data. The headers of the table should be the keys of the dictionary (e.g. _v,_id,approved) and the data of the table should be the values of the dictionary in 3 different rows.

My problem is that with below code I only manage to get a dataframe with one row which is the last element of the dictionary.

Could you please advise how can I get the desired table? I have try to find an answer in similar questions but I was not able to solve my issue. Below is the code I am using:

```
import pymongo
import pprint
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd      

tablas = pd.DataFrame(db.users.find_one())

for post in tablas:
    tablas.append(post, ignore_index=True)
tablas.to_excel('check.xlsx')
```

The expected dataframe should look like below:

[image]

Comment: You can please provide `Tablas` with correct syntax? Also, show the expected dataframe.

Comment: Tablas is 3 dictionaries

Comment: So a list of dicts?

Comment: Where is `db` defined? Please show a [mcve]. Why are you looping over the same list you are appending to? And maybe you get only one result because `find_one()` only returned one element??

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the data loaded:

```
Tablas = [{'__v': 0,
      '_id': 'a',
      'approved': True},
      {'__v': 1,
      '_id': 'b',
      'approved': True},
      {'__v': 2,
      '_id': 'c',
      'approved': True}]

t=pd.DataFrame(Tablas)

t.to_excel('check.xlsx')
```